# FCM ionic2 not working

Tags: firebase, ionic2, cordova-plugin-fcm

I put the `google-services.json` file in the root ionic project,
I installed the requirements:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/fcm
```

and then in app.module

```
import {FCM} from '@ionic-native/fcm'
providers [FCM]
```

in app.component i don't know how to use it ....